# Beautifulsoup4 - Trying to get the data using a while loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written a very basic crawler to check if a link is dead or not using bs4.
I want to check if the anchor tag has an href or not (This way I can check if the link is active or not). There is only one anchor element in the page.

This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check():
    url = 'https://somewebsite.net/'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = a.get('href')
        if href != '':
            print('a')
        else:
            print('b')
check()
```

This works fine but i want the crawler to keep checking the website every few seconds. I tried implementing this using a infinite while loop but i did not get any results.

```
while True:
    check()
```

I want to know why this did not work and any possible solutions.
Thank You.

Comment: I guess you should act according to websites. Because may be that `<a>` tag has `src` attribute in (i.e a file as a link).And if you want program to check for every few seconds you can have `time.sleep()` method from `time` module. Enter no. of seconds you wanna wait for program to check again.

Comment: Do you get an error if you wait on it for a while? You may be waiting for `requests` to time out and hit its retry limit, which can be configured. Additionally, you could do a `request.head` to only get a head request to check the status code if you're only interested if it's alive or dead. Same as above applies though

Comment: @GadaaDhaariGeek the anchor tag has a href attribute not a src attribute.

Comment: @Gator_Python i did not get an error when i tried running it in a loop 50 times. But i will try the request.head thing.

Comment: Are you getting an error ever?

How are you confirming that the loop is running and completing? Look at the html output, can you confirm there is an anchor tag? (look at it from your code, not the website by a browser) If the loop is, in fact completing, but not providing output, that probably means there are no anchor tags, meaning that the code under `for a in soup.findAll("a")` never runs.

Comment: @Gator_Python it works fine when executed once or used in a for loop.

Comment: You get no output whatsoever? No errors? Put some print statements inside the function and outside the function in the `while True` loop to see where you can find out where it's hanging.

Comment: @Gator_Python i get no errors or output. However i will try running the loop with a few print statements.

Comment: Why are you using find_all if there is only one link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what website you're trying to check tags on, but at least from a code standpoint, you should probably be doing `not a.has_attr('href')` rather than `a.get('href') != ''` if your objective is to see if the anchor has any `href` attribute at all.

Also, it looks like you may have intended for your `if` statements to be part of your `for`-loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check():
    url = 'https://somewebsite.net/'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if a.has_attr('href'):
            print('b')
        else:
            print('a')
check()
```

You will probably also want to sleep for a bit to check every few seconds, rather than constantly.

```
import time
...
while True:
    time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds
    check()
```

Comment: I guess `if` statement should be the part of `for` loop. Then only he can check for every `<a>' tag.

Comment: Yes I am sorry for the mistake made in the for loop (fixed it). I tried the sleep thing but that did not work either.

Comment: I tried running this in a for loop which iterates for 50 times that seemed to work but its not working with the while loop

Answer (score 0):

`a.get('href')` will never be equal to an empty string, it will be *None* if the anchor has no href so you if would never evaluate to True.

If there is only one anchor then just `return soup.find("a", href=True)`, if there is an anchor with a href you will get the anchor, if not you will get None,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

def check():
    url = 'https://somewebsite.net/'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')
    return soup.find("a", href=True)


while True:
   a = check()
   if a:
       # do whatever
    sleep(10)
```